# how do i embed the pdf gallery in wordpress post

Tags: gallery, pdf

I want to show the epaper of newspaper.
Is there a way that i can embed a gallery of pdf  in post just like the gallery of images

Comment: @cybmeta I tried creating the gallery of pdf but its not possible i think.. There were some solutions like upload a thumbnail and pdf. Then add that thumbnail to post and then change the custom url of that thumbnail so as to point to pdf.But it doesn't seem possible in case of gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Custom URL* field, to modify the attachment link for each one of your gallery images:

[image: Custom Attachment's URL]

where this is supported by the following plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:   Custom Attachments Links
 * Description:   Adds a new media field, to override the default attachment links.
 * Plugin URI:    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176668/26350
 * Plugin Author: Birgir Erlendsson (birgire)
 * Version:       0.0.1
 */

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', function( $fields, $post )
{
    $fields['wpse_custom_attachment_url'] = array(
        'label' => 'Custom URL',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpse_custom_attachment_url', true ),
        'helps' => "Override the attachment's default",
    );
    return $fields;
}, 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', function( $post, $attachment )
{
    if( isset( $attachment['wpse_custom_attachment_url'] ) )
        update_post_meta( 
            $post['ID'], 
            'wpse_custom_attachment_url', 
            $attachment['wpse_custom_attachment_url'] 
        ); 
    return $post;
}, 10, 2 );

! is_admin() && add_filter( 'attachment_link', function( $link, $pid )
{
    if( $url = get_post_meta( $pid, 'wpse_custom_attachment_url', true ) )
        $link = esc_url( $url );   
    return $link;
}, 10, 2 );
```